# Prove that $\forall x[-1, 1]$ exist two random variables such that their correlation is $x$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation

The task is to prove that $\forall x\in[-1, 1]\ \ \exists \xi, \eta$ - random variables such that $\text{Corr}(\xi, \eta)=x$.

I've tried using the following formula:
$$\text{Corr}(\xi, \eta)=\frac{\text{Cov}(\xi, \eta)}{\sqrt{\mathbb D\xi}\sqrt{\mathbb D\eta}}=\frac{\mathbb E(\xi \cdot \eta) - \mathbb E\xi \mathbb E\eta}{\sqrt{\mathbb D\xi}\sqrt{\mathbb D\eta}}$$
While $\mathbb E \xi, \mathbb E\eta, \mathbb D\xi, \mathbb D\eta$ can take any value $\in \mathbb R$ independently of each other, I'm not sure how to deal with $\mathbb E(\xi \cdot \eta)$.

Comment: When $-1 < x < 1$, just consider a bivariate normal random vector $(\xi, \eta)$ with the correlation parameter $x$. If $|x| = 1$, take any random variable $\xi$, then let $\eta = \pm \xi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. with a standard normal distribution and $\xi=aX+bY, \eta=Y$ then $corr(\xi,\eta)=\frac b {\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}}$. For any $x \in [-1,1]$ we can choose real numbers $a,b$ such that $\frac b {\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}}=x$. [Take $b=x,a =\sqrt {1-x^{2}}$].